# Strongest beings in High School DxD

Tags: high-school-dxd

Who are the strongest beings in *High School DxD*?

If they can be ranked, it's even better. If not, at least I'd like to know why they are strong.

Comment: The leaders of each faction should be the strongest. In Devil's case that would be the 4 Maou. The Great Red and Ophis the Ouroboros is also among the strongest, but we cannot tell who is the absolute strongest since they don't fight much. They are just strongest from being said as such.

Answer (score 3):

According to the author:

> In no particular order Ophis, Shiva, Vishnu, Brahma, Śakra, Thor, Typhon (Or Fenrir), Hades, Aten, and Lugh.
>
> That's how it is. Great Red isn't included because it is a creature who basically doesn't fight (I get many claim that this isn't true!), and it is the ranking before Ophis and Fenrir lost their powers. What you will have to pay attention to are the Hindu mythology which hasn't appeared in the series yet. Well, those who know about their mythology know it, but the Hindu Gods all have cheat-like abilities. If I make them appear in DxD, it will turn out like the battle in Dragon Ball, so I controlled myself. The Hindu mythology will be placed in the higher ranks of the Top-10 strongest that Vali spoke about. It truly is terrifying. If DxD continues to go on for much longer, I'm thinking of doing "The Destruction God Shiva arc" as a last resort. So I have no plan to make them appear until then. By the way the true Sirzechs and the serious Ajuka will be placed among the ranks.

the above comes from a fan translation of the [Afterword found in *High School DxD: Volume 13*](https://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=High_School_DxD:Volume_13_Afterword)

In an interview, he also mentions Azazel is likely to be in the top 10 once he powers up enough (he's a genius that creates gears and stuff so it doesn't come as a surprise).

I can tell you the top 3 are: Ophis (before what happened in volume 11. Poor girl...), Trixeha and Great Red. The Hindu Gods would come afterward After that the rest of the list

So basically there are 3 tiers between the strongest beings.

All of them are over the top though. Remember how tough it was to defeat Loki? (Vali + his team + Issei + Rias team + Azazel + Akeno's father, leader of Fallen angels) and still, they needed Thor's hammer. Well, Loki isn't even among the strongest beings.

Comment: @Memor-X  http://aminoapps.com/page/anime/3056970/top-10-strongest-high-school-dxd-characters This link is pretty good too. I agree with pretty much everything he says and he even references the volumes to defend his point of view. I didn't make a clear ranking considering the exact ranks of some of them is opinion-based. For example, Sirzechs is stronger than Hades, but saying he's number 7 is an opinion, we don't know if Thor is stronger for example.

Comment: generally you should link to your source in your question....is what i want to say however from your link in one click someone can download the unofficial fan translations of High School DxD, this is different from a site translating an interview of an author, but on the other hand your link shows it comes from the light novel itself. for the moment i'll edit your question to indicate where the quote comes from. if you get information from fan translations in my view generally it is acceptable to indicate where in the material it came from like i have done